# I am having an error in calling event api of Microsft Graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to create the event in MicroSoft Calendar using postman api calls but I am getting below error This seems to be the issue of generating access token. this same thing works in Microsoft graph explorer as it has auto generated token.

I tried to generate tokens using client creds grant type and authoriazation_code grant type but using that token I can't call create event api .

[image: error with beta]
[image: error with v1]

Comment: Could you please provide us more details, what you have tried , what parameter you entered to generate token?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the doc to get access token - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks @vickcy , but I have already tried this . The token generated by this is giving me the error shared above . Can you please help me with that .

Comment: thanks for the update , have you license the user for Exchange Online/provision a mailbox? This endpoint corresponds to calendar events, and in order to fetch those you need to have a mailbox.